# track by $index shows too many results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I got the following error from Angular:

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.
```

So I fixed it by doing the following:

```
rooster in rooster.uren track by $index
```

But what that did, was create a ton of panels, while my jSon only has 4 lines.

The JS:

```
angular.module("PixelFM").controller("grootRoosterController", function ($http) {
    var that = this;
    that.uren = [];
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/assets/scripts/GROOTROOSTERTEST.json'
    }).success(function(data) {
        that.uren = data;
    });
});
```

the html that repeats repeats:

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="rooster in rooster.uren track by $index">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body grootrooster">
            {{rooster.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for some odd reason, what this code does is output a million panels, which all stay empty...

How's this possible? Thanks.

EDIT

Json;

```
[
    {"host": "Adjuh5", "showname": "", "hour": "1446674064", "cohost": "Finicky"},
    {"host": "Beatgrid", "showname": "", "hour": "1446674064", "cohost": ""},
    {"host": "Adjuh5", "showname": "", "hour": "1446674064", "cohost": ""},
    {"host": "Finicky", "showname": "", "hour": "1446674064", "cohost": ""}
]
```

Comment: Circular reference? `ng-repeat="rooster in rooster.uren track by $index"` => `ng-repeat="r in rooster.uren track by $index"`

Comment: Include in your question the response json

Comment: @EmirMarques I added it

Comment: Check the length of rooster.uren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me! Check your call $http and change:

```
angular.module("PixelFM").controller("grootRoosterController", function ($http) {
    var that = this;
    that.uren = [];
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/assets/scripts/GROOTROOSTERTEST.json'
    }).success(function(data) {
        that.uren = data;
    });
});
```

To:

```
angular.module("PixelFM").controller("grootRoosterController", function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.rooster = {uren:[];
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/assets/scripts/GROOTROOSTERTEST.json'
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.rooster.uren = data;
    });
});
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.rooster = {
    uren: [{
      "host": "Adjuh5",
      "showname": "",
      "hour": "1446674064",
      "cohost": "Finicky"
    }, {
      "host": "Beatgrid",
      "showname": "",
      "hour": "1446674064",
      "cohost": ""
    }, {
      "host": "Adjuh5",
      "showname": "",
      "hour": "1446674064",
      "cohost": ""
    }, {
      "host": "Finicky",
      "showname": "",
      "hour": "1446674064",
      "cohost": ""
    }]
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <hr/>Quick-Ng-Repeat
  <hr/>
  <div ng-repeat="rooster in rooster.uren">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body grootrooster">
        {{rooster.host}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```